# Best way to fix: Acces to path 'C:\..\USB-map' is denied because map is already used

Tags: c#, streamwriter, special-folders, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I am trying to make to create a .cmd file with this code into it: `call .\CopyToTarget.cmd w60 glb "C:\Users\oma\me\trunk-r664\USB-map"`. I am creating this code ~5 times.

But since `\trunk-r664\` is already in use it seems like I cannot write: `@"\trunk-r664\USB-map"` into the .cmd file for some reason. Does anyone know how to fix it? It keeps getting me the error: `UnauthorizedAccesExpection was unhandled, ccess to the path 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\trunk-r664\USB-map' is denied.`

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) 
+ "\\trunk-r664\\trunk\\cmd\\custom\\RunAll.cmd"))
{
    for (int j=0;j<installeerlijst64.Count;j++)
    {
        sw.WriteLine("call .\\CopyToTarget.cmd " + installeerlijst64[j] + " glb" + 
File.CreateText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\trunk-r664\USB-map"));
    }
}
```

I tried this too, but it tells me I am using an illegal character:

```
"\""+File.CreateText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
+ @"\trunk-r664\USB-map" + "\""));
```

Comment: Please note that  `UnauthorizedAccessException` and `already in use` are two different errors and may occurred due to two different reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.CreateText` will create a new file. First time when `for` loop execute, it will create and open the file USB-map and hold the handle of that file. During second iteration of `for` loop, it will try to do the same thing. Hence, already in use error.

Remove `File.CreateText` and you will get the desired result.

```
sw.WriteLine("call .\\CopyToTarget.cmd " + installeerlijst64[j] + " glb " + "\"" + 
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\trunk-r664\USB-map" + "\"");
```